# Function or tag in PhP to send an email with attachment

Tags: php, attachment, email-attachments

I'm looking for a function or tag in PhP by which I can send an email to a user with a pdf file attached.
I'm a graphic designer with little PhP knowledge. I will appreciate if you give me an example how to do such a thing

Answer (score 0):

u can use this on phpmailer framework

```
$mail->addAttachment($path, $name, $encoding, $type);
```

Solid framework wheres the [link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial)